# mysql update table from another with newest post

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.
I would like to update table posts with newest posts from table postsEdit (timestamp comparison).
Can you please help me with query?

Table 1 posts
- postId is primary key, 
- timestamp is ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```
postId | post  | timestamp

1      | Books | 2016-02-02 16:31:05
2      | TVs   | 2016-02-02 18:25:01
3      | Food  | 2016-02-01 16:43:13
4      | Drink | 2016-02-02 16:30:59
5      | etc   | 2016-02-02 16:01:34
```

Table 2 postsEdit
- editId is primary key,
- timestamp is ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

In this table are newest posts and from this table I would like to copy to table post. Posts will reamin here.

```
editId | postId | post   | timestamp

1      | 1      | Phone  | 2015-02-01 23:01:15
2      | 2      | Radio  | 2016-02-06 21:14:12
3      | 5      | Music  | 2016-02-05 22:06:24
4      | 1      | Comics | 2016-02-07 23:01:15
```

Thanks a lot, TommyB

Comment: You should really be doing this with a trigger, if you want `posts` to always have the most recent data.

Comment: I don't really understand this table structure.  What are these tables storing in relation to each other?  If someone is editing a `Post`, why are they not editing the record in the `Posts` table to do so?

Comment: Update query I will execute manually

Comment: Is this being done as a ONE-OFF-FIX or something you want to happen always as part of your normal running of the system????

Comment: Because of eliminating human mistakes in table posts I create table postsEdit. After check new post in postsEdit I update table posts